# Creating and inputting data into nested arrays - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a programme that takes names and adds them into arrays. The trick is I need to store them in nested arrays, so I ask the user for a number - this defines the number of groups. Then the user is asked for names - these need to then be sorted as such...

- As an example, imagine there are three groups.

  - First person goes in the first group.
  - Second person goes in the second group.
  - Third person goes in the third group.
  - Fourth person goes in the first group.
  - Fifth person goes in the second group.
  - etc.

I'm working on the conditions, and they are pretty much OK I think.
But the rest of it I'm pretty stumped on...I dont really understand how I'm meant to send them to nested arrays.

```
groups = []

#enter the number of groups
puts "give me a number"
count = gets.to_i

while true do

puts 'Give me a name'
user_input = gets.chomp
groups.push(user_input)
groups.delete("stop")

if user_input == "stop"

puts "Give me a group number"
puts groups[gets.to_i]

#puts'es the names from that group

break

end
end
```

This doesn't seem a million miles off, but I'm not really sure where I'm going with it.

```
count = 3
user_input = ["joe","sally","frank"]

groups = Array.new(count) {Array.new(user_input)}
```

Any help would be SO appreciated, very very new to this

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to create the nested array based on the given number:

```
puts 'Enter number of groups'
count = gets.to_i
groups = Array.new(count) { [] }
```

If the user enters <kbd>3</kbd>, you'd have an array containing 3 other arrays:

```
groups = Array.new(3) { [] }
#=> [[], [], []]
```

It's important to use the *block form* for [`Array.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-c-new) so each inner array is a separate instance. (see "Common gotchas" in the docs)

With the nested structure in place, we can append the names to the inner arrays. Either by using a "counter" variable `i` and pushing to `group[i]`:

```
puts 'Enter names or "stop" when done'

i = 0                  # start at 0
loop do
  user_input = gets.chomp
  break if user_input == 'stop'
  groups[i].push(user_input)

  if i < count - 1
    i += 1             # increment
  else
    i = 0              # start over
  end
end
```

Or – much more elegant – via [`cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-cycle):

```
puts 'Enter names or "stop" when done'

groups.cycle do |group|
  user_input = gets.chomp
  break if user_input == 'stop'
  group.push(user_input)
end
```

Comment: I tried youe code with `loop` and it doesn't work correctly

Comment: You fixed it. Now OK.

Comment: @mechnicov I had the upper bound hard-coded, i.e. `2` instead of `count - 1`. Was a follow-up typo from the example before. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

After having obtained the number of groups, say

```
ngroups = 3
```

the code will prompt the user to enter a series of names, followed by `"stop"` when the user has no more names to enter. Suppose the user enters the following strings, in the order indicated:

```
"Lucy\n", "Hank\n", "Billy-Bob\n", "Trixie\n", "Veronica\n", "Roxy\n",
"Norm\n", "Herb\n", "stop\n"
```

We could create the desired array with the following code:

```
0.step.with_object(Array.new(ngroups) { [] }) do |i,a|
  print 'Please enter a name or "stop" if finished: '
  reply = gets.chomp
  break a if reply == "stop"
  a[i % ngroups] << reply     
end
  #=> [["Lucy", "Trixie", "Norm"], ["Hank", "Veronica", "Herb"],
  #    ["Billy-Bob", "Roxy"]]
```

Note that I did not ask the user to enter a group for each name. That's because you said names were to be assigned to groups in group-order, resuming with the first group after each assignment of a name to the last group.

For anyone new to Ruby this code must look fairly complicated. It is, however, very Ruby-like, and any Rubiest will understand it immediately after having gained some experience with the language. Let me break down the steps. With patience you should be able to understand what's going on.

**[Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step), an enumerator**

```
enum0 = 0.step #=> (0.step)
```

If you examine the doc for this method you will see that `0.step` without a block returns an enumerator, which is an instance of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html). Enumerators are very important in Ruby. They generate values which may be passed to other methods or to block. Here, `enum0` generates the following sequence:

```
enum0.next #=> 0
enum0.next #=> 1
enum0.next #=> 2
```

...*ad infinitum*. See [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

Similarly,

```
e = 21.step(by: -3) #=> (21.step(by: -3)) 
e.next #=> 21 
e.next #=> 18 

e = 2.34.step #=> (2.34.step) 
e.next #=> 2.34 
e.next #=> 3.34
```

**[Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object)**

We don't actually need to use this method. We could instead write the following, which gives the same result:

```
a = []
0.step do |i|
  print 'Please enter a name or "stop" if finished: '
  reply = gets.chomp
  break a if reply == "stop"
  a[i % ngroups] << reply     
end
a
```

As you see, the use of `each_object` merely saves two lines of code: `a = []` and `a` at the end.<sup>1</sup>. This method--and its cousin, [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html), which are widely-used by Ruby coders, are actually quite simple.

**Another enumerator**

Next we have:

```
enum1 = enum0.with_object(Array.new(ngroups) { [] })
  #=> #<Enumerator: (0.step):with_object([[], [], []])>
```

As you see from the return value for `enum1`, `enum1` can be thought of as a *compound enumerator*, though Ruby has no such formal concept. Let's see what values this enumerator generates:

```
enum1.next #=> [0, [[], [], []]] 
enum1.next #=> [1, [[], [], []]] 
enum1.next #=> [2, [[], [], []]]
```

You see that each value generated is an array of two elements, the first a counter starting at zero, the second an array of three groups. The groups are now empty but they will be filled out as calculations proceed.

If we wished we could now write the original code as follows<sup>1</sup>

```
enum1.each do |i,a|
  print 'Please enter a name or "stop" if finished: '
  reply = gets.chomp
  break a if reply == "stop"
  a[i % ngroups] << reply     
end
```

See [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-each).

**Passing elements generated by `enum1` to the block**

When the first element is generated and passed to the block, the block variables `i` and `a` are assigned values as follows:

```
i, a = enum1.next #=> [0, [[], [], []]] 
i #=> 0 
a #=> [[], [], []]
```

The process of breaking the array returned by `enum1.next` into its components is called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). It is a powerful and valuable tool.

We can now perform the block operations.

```
print 'Please enter a name or "stop" if finished: '
reply = "Lucy" # = gets.chomp
break a if reply == "stop" # do not break
a[i % ngroups] << reply     
  #=> a[0 % 3] << "Lucy"
  #=> a[0] << "Lucy"
  #=> ["Lucy"]
```

Next `enum1` generates it's second value and passes it to the block, values are assigned to the block variables and the block operations are performed.

```
i, a = enum1.next #=> [1, [["Lucy"], [], []]] 
i #=> 1 
a #=> [["Lucy"], [], []]
```

Notice that `a` has been update to reflect `"Lucy"` having been appended to `a[0]`. Continuing,

```
print 'Please enter a name or "stop" if finished: '
reply = "Hank" # = gets.chomp
break a if reply == "stop" # do not break
a[i % ngroups] << reply
  #=> a[1 % 3] << "Hank"
  #=> a[1] << "Hank"
  #=> ["Hank"]
```

Now,

```
a #=> => [["Lucy"], ["Hank"], []]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

<sup>1. Before running the following I need to execute `enum1.rewind` to re-initialise the enumerator. See [Enumerator#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind).</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'm having trouble using the first example you gave - it works perfectly but I can't figure out how to then access the array, what is it called? If I wanted to say access the second array what would I do?

the `0.step do |i|` you gave makes the most sense in my head but it wont run for me.

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow, but in the meantime, please be more specific about `o.step do |i|` "won't run for me". Is an exception raised? If so what is the error message and on what line does the error occur? What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: ah sorry! Im using repl.it - 2.5.0

`undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
(repl):9:in `block in <main>'
(repl):5:in `step'
(repl):5:in `<main>'`